# In Jira I want a scrum board for all the stories and tasks for an epic

Tags: jira, agile, scrum

I have a requirement to have a scrum board for a single epic, showing all the stories and tasks in those stories.

How do I set up a filter that is "this epic and all things related to it" to create a board from?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about project management, not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Issue navigator you can Search for Issue and type "Epic Link" = "insert name of epic" and press search. After that press Save as and give it a filter name. Then Go to Agile, Manage boards, and create a new board based on a filter.